# creating wifi hotspot for Galaxy note

Tags: networking, wireless, network-bridge

I follow the steps mentioned in many blog but my wifi AP is not scanned by my phone.

My system config:-
Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit

> 00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
>
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
>
> 04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
>
> 08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)

Please tell me you need any other info of my system...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using network-manger in Ubuntu, it's an `Ad hoc` wifi network and android don't recognize them. Therefore you have to create a true `Access Point` wifi network, with `hostap` for example.
However, custom android ROMs such as CyanogenMod can connect to Ad Hoc wifi networks.

If you are already trying to set up a true Ad Hoc wifi network, then the problem may not come from android. Maybe it comes from your computer, some (all?) Intel wifi chipsets are known not to work well with hostap, which can be solved by buying a supported usb wifi dongle (even if buying another thing is not a really good solution).

Comment: Same problem I am facing when I am using my laptop with Windows 7.
With "Conitify-me" software.
In there forum They suggested to upgrade the Wifi driver and It started work for me.
Please tell me if any way to make it working on by ubuntu OS...Because most of the Time I have to boot my machine with ubuntu..

If you any logs/ command output please tell me.